# Add 2 textChangedListeners to edittext?

Tags: android

I'm creating a class that contains a `EditText` and when this `EditText` changes I store the value in a variable in this class.

But I also need this value in an other class and I want to update this value everytime the `EditText` changes.

So what is the best solution to this problem? How can I notify my other class that the `EditText` has changed? 
The `EditText`already has a `textChangedListener`, but can I add a second `textChangedListener` without overwriting the first?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a callback to the other class:

http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TextView.addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)

This will `add` another listener rather than replace already existing listener.

Comment: Thanks, I used the callback method because it suited this situation better but now I know that I can use multiple listeners :)

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher is an Interface . make a class implementaing it . Create a constructor accepting the EditText and give callback to activity class holding views in case when user is leaving the activity in onPause or onStop . Then on another screen give another instance of class to edittext and do the same .